# Geometrical definition of loop group

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

On pp.89 of these [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/m392c_Knotes.pdf) live TEX-ed by Arun Debray for Dan Freed's K-theory [course](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/) there is a geommetrical definition of loop group of a compact Lie group $G$.

Let $P \to S^1$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $L_P{G}$ the group of automorphisms $\varphi$ of $P$ that cover $\text{id}_{S^1}$.  If $P = S^1 \times G$ then it says that there is a very natural identification with "the" loop group: such an automorphism $\varphi$ is a loop through the action of $G$.

I am not quite sure of the last sentence, that such an automorphism $\varphi$ is a loop through the action of $G$ provides a natural identification of $L_P{G}$ with "the" loop group (and why double quote "the"?).  Could somebody help to clarify?